# If $x^3+px+q$ is irreducible over a finite field then $-4p^3-27q^2$ is a square

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Suppose that $x^3+px+q$ is irreducible over a finite field $F$ with characteristic not equal to $2$ or $3$. Show that $-4p^3-27q^2$ is a square in $F$.

I noticed that the determinant of $f=x^3+px+q$ is actually $-4p^3-27q^2$. But I have no idea how to use this fact to prove the statement. Any idea?

Comment: www.mscand.dk/article/download/10366/8387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the discriminant is always a square in the splitting field. In your case the splitting field has degree 3 over $F$, and an extension of degree $3$ does not admit any 'new squares'. Hence it is already square in $F$.